# Is a sequence of identical distributed integrable random variables even uniformly integrable?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, uniform-integrability

Let $\{X_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of identically distributed random variables in $L^1$. Is this sequence uniformly integrable?

I have to show that
$$
\lim_{c \to \infty} \sup_{n \geq 1} E\big[\mathbf{1}_{\{ |X_n| > c\}} \, |X_n|\big] = 0.
$$

By Chebyshev's inequality we have 
$$
E\big[\mathbf{1}_{\{ |X_n| > c\}}\big] \leq \frac{E[|X_n|]}{c}
$$
and since $E[X_n]$ is finite, this converges to zero as $c$ converges to infinity.

Now there are two questions remaining:

1. Does $E[\mathbf{1}_{\{ |X_n| > c\}}] \to 0$ imply also $E[\mathbf{1}_{\{ |X_n| > c\}} \, |X_n|] \to 0$?
2. Does the assumption of same distributions imply that $E[\mathbf{1}_{\{ |X_n| > c\}} \, |X_n|] = E[\mathbf{1}_{\{ |X_1| > c\}} \, |X_1|]$?

Comment: Hint: Can you show that if $X$ is integrable then the singleton $\{X\}$ is uniformly integrable?

Comment: @Did I think your hint is answered by the answer of saz (dominated convergence).

Comment: Then can you apply the hint to solve your problem?

Answer (score 4):

Since the random variables are identically distributed, we have

$$\mathbb{E}(1_{\{|X_n| > c\}} |X_n|) = \mathbb{E}(1_{\{|X_1|>c\}} |X_1|)$$

for all $n \geq 1$ and therefore

$$\sup_{n \geq 1} \mathbb{E}(1_{\{|X_n| > c\}} |X_n|) = \mathbb{E}(1_{\{|X_1|>c\}} |X_1|).$$

As $X_1$ is integrable, the right-hand side converges to $0$ as $c \to \infty$; this follows for instance from the dominated convergence theorem or the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: We have $\lim_{c \to \infty} 1_{\{|X_1| > c\}} = 1_{\{X_1 = \infty\}}$ pointwise, but $P(|X_1| = \infty) = 0$, since $|X_1|$ is integrable. $1_{\{|X_1| > c\}} |X_1|$ is dominated by the integrable function $|X_1|$, therefore by dominated convergence $\lim_{c \to \infty} E(1_{\{|X_1|>c\}} |X_1|) = E(1_{A} |X_1|) = 0$, since $A = \{|X_1| = \infty\}$ is a set of measure zero. Is this correct?

Comment: Monotone convergence uses non-decreasing functions, which is not the case here ...

Comment: "Monotone convergence uses non-decreasing functions" Hmmm... no, not at all.

Comment: @user63841219 Yes, your reasoning is correct. However, as Did already pointed out, the monotone convergence theorem is not restricted to non-decreasing functions.